# php some magic way to automatically call a method when another one is called

Tags: php, inheritance

I have a base class and I want to have one of its methods called after the extending class is constructed. Ideally this should happen without changing the extended class constructor:

```
class BaseClass {
    protected function doSomethingAfterConstruct() {}
}

class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass {
   public function __construct() {
       // some custom constructor code
   }
}
```

I could just call `$this->doSomethingAfterConstruct()` at the end of the ExtendedClass constructor or by calling `parent::__construct`, but I am looking for a solution where I can implement this behavior by only changing the baseclass.

Comment: The base class doesn't know anything about a class which extends it. I think you're asking the impossible

Comment: You should be using `parent::__construct` without any magic involved inside child class constructor

Comment: The only way I can think of is, as you suggest - calling `parent::__construct()`, which I think is a good practice. Besides that, I think @ADyson is correct - you have to make the parent class aware of its children manually - or build the framework with some callbacks, which will be a headache - if it is possible..

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. There's a bunch of patterns in that area, like Decorator, Facade, or Monitor/Observer, apart from that.

Comment: the problem with parent::__construct(); it's that anyway should be called at the beginning of the subclass constructor. As said it's impossible in terms of OOP for the base class to know when the subclass finished to construct. Surely it's a convoluted need that could be addressed differently. To get as close as possible you may have a protected method in your base class expected to be called by the subclass at the end of the constructor.

Comment: I like the way Laravel introduces ["boot" methods](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L182) to deliver similar behaviour. [I created an example on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/VZ4gc) to demonstrate how it could be introduced to your example but really this doesn't stop the manual need to execute the methods stated - just gives you more control to do it. It likely doesn't help much with your example directly but the concept of utilising traits might help.

Comment: It seems that what I am looking for would be something similar to Decorators in typescript, but php does not seem to have something like that

Answer (score 0):

If it would be not `__constructor`, but ordinary method, then you can use `__call` magic method to *proxy* calls to child class:

**All child methods should be non-public visibility, to trigger magic method**

```php
class BaseClass {
    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
         $return = $this->{$name}(...$arguments);

         $this->doSomethingAfterMethod();

         return $return;
    }

    protected function doSomethingAfterMethod() {}
}

class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass {
   private function randomMethod() {
       // some custom method code
   }
}
```